# How to ensure which email's are dummy or not hosted using sendgrid php

Tags: php, email, smtp, sendgrid

We have to send bulk emails using sendgrid smtp emails,
issue is when email's having dummy account or not hosted / not exists email, sendgrid account is deducting email counters from my balance emails,

how to ensure / get details of all emails which are not sent,

we have tried

```
$cl_email   = new SendGrid\Email();
    $cl_email->setFrom($sysEmail);
    $cl_email->setFromName($sysCompany);
    $cl_email->setTos($user_email);
    $cl_email->setSubject($subject);
    $cl_email->setHtml($message);
    $response = $sendgrid->send($cl_email);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [invalid emails](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/invalid_emails.html) API endpoint and the [bounces](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/bounces.html) API endpoint to get the emails that are bouncing or are invalid, then you can remove them from your list. Or you can use the [event webhook](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html) and then handle the bounces as they happen.